# Register a Service for IHubContext Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, service, controller

I want to register a service, but i have errors:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Atos.TvView.WebAdmin.Hubs.HubPublisher`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`1[Atos.TvView.WebAdmin.Hubs.StatisticsHub]]' while attempting to activate 'Atos.TvView.WebAdmin.Controllers.ChannelController'.

My Code looks like:

**Base Class**

```cs
public class HubPublisher<T> : IHubPublisher<Hub> where T : IHubContext<Hub>
{
    private readonly T _hub;

    public HubPublisher(T hub)
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }

    public async Task Send(string message)
    {
        await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveData", message);
    }
}
```

**Class I want to register**

```cs
public class StatisticsPublisher : HubPublisher<IHubContext<StatisticsHub>>
{
    public StatisticsPublisher(IHubContext<StatisticsHub> hub) : base(hub)
    {
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```cs
services.AddScoped<IHubPublisher<Hub>, StatisticsPublisher>();
...

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<StatisticsHub>("/statisticsHub");
```

**StatisticsHub***

```cs
public class StatisticsHub : Hub { }
```

**Controller***

```cs
public class ChannelController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubPublisher<StatisticsHub> _statisticsPublisher;

    public ChannelController(IHubPublisher<StatisticsHub> statisticsPublisher)
    {
        _statisticsPublisher = statisticsPublisher;
    }
}
```

Comment: The posted exception does not match with the code for the `ChannelController`.  The  exception is telling that the container is trying to resolve `HubPublisher<T>` while the `ChannelController`'s constructor has an `IHubPublisher<T>`. Please check the `ChannelController`, it likely references `HubPublisher<T>` instead of `IHubPublisher<T>`.